# Segmentation Fault in strcpy()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcpy

I have a basic structure like this

```
typedef struct struck {
    char* id;
    char* mat;
    int value;
    char* place;
} *Truck;
```

And afunction like this which creates a new "instance" of that struct:

```
Truck CTruck(char* id, char* mat, int value, char* place) {
    Truck nT = (Truck) malloc(sizeof (Truck));
    nT->value = value;
    strcpy(nT->id, id);
    strcpy(nT->mat, mat);
    strcpy(nT->place, place);
    return nT;
}
```

I'm getting an error in the first `strcpy`. It compiles without problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your typedef defines `Truck` as a `struct struck *`, i.e. a pointer. So it's size will be `4` or `8` depending on the architecture and not the size of the struct

Use `sizeof(*Truck)` to get the actual size of the struct.

You also need to allocate memory for the characters. The easiest way would be using `strdup()`.

```
Truck CTruck(const char* id, const char* mat, int value, const char* place) {
    Truck nT = malloc(sizeof (*Truck));
    nT->value = value;
    nT->id = strdup(id);
    nT->mat = strdup(mat);
    nT->place = strdup(place);
    return nT;
}
```

---

However, I would suggest changing your typedef so it's an alias for the struct, not for a pointer to it:

```
typedef struct {
    char* id;
    char* mat;
    int value;
    char* place;
} Truck;
```

In your function you then use this:

```
Truck *nT = malloc(sizeof(Truck));
```

Comment: +1 And also malloc some space for id, mat and place so the strcpy's don't obliterate random memory.

Comment: `strdup` ftw; no need to use malloc and that nasty `strcpy`

Comment: I have more structs using *Stuff on the end of the typedef, and if I change that to }Truck it gives erros on every of them, and that `malloc(sizeof(Truck))` wont work if I use *Truck

Comment: Alright i guess the problem was also in using the strcpy, i didn't knew that *strdup*, thanks to all

Comment: +1 for telling the person to use `typedef` as an alias for a `struct`

Answer (score 7):

`nT->id` is just a pointer. Need to `malloc` memory to copy the string into. Ditto for the others.

Answer (score 4):

Your usage of `sizeof` is incorrect. In general, the argument to `malloc()` needs to be "the size of that which the returned pointer is pointing at". In other words, you need `sizeof *nT`. See how that also eliminates repeating the type name (`Truck`)?

Also, in C you [don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858); it serves no purpose, can hide an actual error, and makes the code harder to read.

As others have pointed out, you're also not allocating space for any string data, all you have are the pointers in your structure.